# symfony translation resources with custom domain doesn't load

Tags: symfony, translation, silex

I have a little problem.
When I add a custom domain to my resource for translation, it doesn't load.

My code working (no custom domain) :

```
$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function ($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());

    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.en_GB.yml', 'en_GB');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.fr_FR.yml', 'fr_FR');

    return $translator;
}));
```

My code I want to do and not working :

```
$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function ($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());

    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.en_GB.yml', 'en_GB', 'back-office');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.fr_FR.yml', 'fr_FR', 'back-office');

    return $translator;
}));
```

the default domain is "messages", how can I change it ?

regards

EDIT :

I just noticed that it doesn't load the other resource files. 
If I add empty file resource first then my translation resource file, translation doesn't appear on my twig files, it print the variable.

```
$translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/messages.en_GB.yml', 'en_GB');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/messages.fr_FR.yml', 'fr_FR');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.en_GB.yml', 'en_GB', 'back-office');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__ . '/../views/backend/translator/translations/back-office.fr_FR.yml', 'fr_FR', 'back-office');
```

EDIT 2 :

I get it, I should specify the domain on each variable in the twig file or specify the default domain on each twig files :

{{ 'label.name'|trans({}, 'app') }}
or
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}

It's really not easy to manage when you have lot of files...

Comment: What exactly is not working? Add example of translation usage.

Comment: Well it doesn't show the translation, just print the variable.

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit more, I should specify the domain on each var on the twig file... like {{ 'show.website'|trans({},'back-office') }} I tough that a simple trans will catch all translation files domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, I should specify the domain on each variable in the twig file or specify the default domain on each twig files :

```
{{ 'label.name'|trans({}, 'app') }}
```

or

```
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}
```

It's really not easy to manage when you have lot of files...